# Create a student contact directory using google sheets?

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I'm planning to create a spreadsheet containing the following student details:

names, chosen subject, group letter, time slot, student bio, student cover letter.

I would like to know if there is an easy way to export this so I can print one student per page in a report like booklet?

Comment: These rows or columns?

Comment: They are rows. Each student per row.

Comment: This sounds similar to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40067/how-do-i-mail-merge-from-google-spreadsheet-to-a-google-document) which asks how to mailmerge from Google Sheets to a Google Document. Have you tried those suggestions (e.g. the Yet Another Mail Merge add-on)?